# When to use dès que, depuis que and à partir de?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, conjonctions

So I understand the difference between *jusqu’à ce que* and *jusqu’à* is that *jusqu’à* is followed by a noun or an action in *infinitif* while *jusqu’à ce que* is followed by a clause with a subject and verb in *subjonctif*. Is that the same case with *dès que* vs *dès* and *depuis que* vs *depuis*? According to what I know, *à partir de* can either be followed by a verbe in *indicatif* or *subjonctif* so when do I know which one to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Depuis que**

"Depuis que" is used to indicate that something that started in the past continues in the present. It is also used to state the time the action started.
It is followed by a subject + verb.
Examples : 
J'habite ici *depuis que* je suis né. => I have been living here since I was born. (That's when it started and it is still true)

**Dès que**

"Dès que" is used to indicate that an action ends right before another start. It has a meaning of direct following of actions. It can also be used for simultaneous actions, in the same way as "Aussitôt que" or "Sitôt que"
Example : 
Je partirai dès qu'ils arriveront. => I will leave as soon as they arrive. (Once the first action is ended, the next one starts)
Dès que j'appuie sur le frein, la voiture ralentit. => As soon as I hit the brakes, the car slows down. (The first and second action are simultaneous in this case)

"Dès" or "Depuis" alone can be followed by a date, a noun for an action or a time.

**À partir de**

"À partir de" and "Dès" have the same meaning but "à partir de" is much more neutral. There is a much lesser meaning of direct continuity between actions.
Example :
J'arrête de fumer à partir de demain. => I will stop smoking tomorrow (I am not quite sure about my english translation here).

Comment: Thank you very much! But is it alright for me to clarify when do I use à partir de with a subjonctif and when do I use à partir de with an indicatif!

Comment: You can't use "à partir de" directly followed by a verb.
It has to be a date : A partir *du* 1er Janvier 2018,
a day : A partir de Lundi 
or a noun : A partir de la fin de l'année

Comment: *À partir de* can also be followed by a location meaning `au delà` : *à partir de la frontière, à partir du péage...*; a starting measurement usually meaning `au dessus` : à partir de 100°, à partir de huit ans, à partir de 3 kg...*; or whatever can be used to start something meaning `out of`:  *fabriquer quelque chose à partir d'autre chose, à partir de rien*.

Comment: I don't think there is simultaneity in "Dès que j'appuie sur le frein, la voiture ralentit", but rather an apparent simultaneity. When your foot steps in the brake pad, it takes some fraction of time before the car starts to slow down. It's just so fast that both events *seem* simultaneous. Could you provide another example in which the events are really simultaneous?